# Adding multiple values from a list as separate numbered keys to a dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing a profile. Every profile has a different amount of "abouts". For example Person 1 has: "lives there", "works there", "eats this". Person 2 has: "lives there".

All my profiles are in a `for` loop which I didn't copy here. In this for loop I made a new loop where I want to get the range of the "abouts" and then create multiple variables containing the content of the "abouts". All this I want to write to my dictionary `friend`.

As output I want:

```
friend = {
    "screenname": profilename, "id": profileid, "username": username, 
    "about 1":  # lives in
    "about 2":  # works at
    # and so on until all the "abouts" are found and written in the dict.
}
```

If I run this code it only puts the latest "about" in my dictionary.

```
for i in range(len(abouts)):
    friend = {
        "screenname": profilename, "id": profileid, "username": username,
        "about " + str(i): abouts[i]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not insert a list into the dictionary key? Given that `abouts` is a list

```
friend = {
    "screenname": profilename, "id": profileid, "username": username, 
    "about": abouts
}
```

Since this is also an ordered collection, it would be much more efficient to fetch data using the index of `about` property

But since your desired output is

```
friend = {
    "screenname": profilename, "id": profileid, "username": username, 
    "about 1":  # lives in
    # and so on...
}
```

You can change your code to:

```
# create your dictionary first
friend = {"screenname": profilename, "id": profileid, "username": username}

for key, value in enumerate(abouts):
    friend["about " + str(key)] = value
```

The problem with your code in your loop is the `friend` variable is being overwritten in every iteration. You need to create your dictionary outside and update the field.

Though personally I would prefer using a list (my first example) instead as stated, as this is a much simpler approach and retrieving/displaying data is much easier.